# Socket programming confusion with windows and unix/linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, sockets

Hello I am trying socket programming in c++.  I need confirmation or say rejection for this logic.  I think `socket.h` header files are designed for UNIX systems whereas for Windows everything is done with `winsock.h`.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6):

For windows, you need `winsock2.h` and `ws2tcpip.h`.

On Linux, you need `sys/socket.h` and `sys/types.h` for the socket functions and `netinet/in.h` for the IP related structs.

Some other differences:

- Windows uses `SOCKET` for socket descriptors while Linux uses `int`
- Windows has `closesocket()` to close sockets, while Linux uses `close()`
- On Windows, you need to call `WSAStartup()` before calling any socket functions, and `WSACleanup()` when you are done using sockets.
- On Linux, you can print errors from socket functions using `perror()` or `strerror()`.  On Windows, you have to call `WSAGetLastError()` to get the error code and `FormatMessage` to get the error text.

Comment: Note that on most platforms, sockets use file descriptors, which is why sockets are represented by `int` and have to be closed by `close()`. On Windows, sockets are actual kernel objects, where `SOCKET` is a handle type, and `closesocket()` exists.

Comment: Also note that not all WinSock functions use `WSAGetLastError()` (`WSAStartup()`, `getaddrinfo()`, `getnameinfo()`, etc) or `FormatMessage()` (`getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()` use `gai_strerror()` instead).

Answer (score 1):

Most platforms implement a BSD-compatible socket API, however different platforms do use different `.h` files to declare their API.  So, to answer your question, Yes, Windows uses `winsock.h` (and `winsock2.h`), whereas POSIX-based platforms like Unix/Linux use `sys/socket.h` instead (`socket.h` is defined as part of the POSIX standard, but Windows is not a POSIX-compatible platform).  If you want to write cross-platform code, you have to take this into account.  As well as other differences, which @dbush outlined in his answer.

Answer (score -2):

Every header file starting with "sys/..." is designed for UNIX environment. As for windows, they tend to use "win" as a prefix to every header file they use.

If you are interested in windows sockets (winsocks) i guess you should start from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx).

As for UNIX sockets, [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/) site seems very interesting and easy going :)

Comment: "*As for windows, they tend to use "win" as a prefix to every header file they use.*" - Although *some* Windows headers *DO* start with a "win" prefix (`winuser.h`, `winnt.h`, `windef.h`, `winsock.h`, etc), a majority of Windows header files *DO NOT*.

Comment: Well thanks for pointing out. Truth is i haven't used many WIndows header files and the ones i did always started with "win" prefix :)

Comment: @Shrawan: I addressed that in my answer.